# Bitmap cache as image source

Tags: easeljs

is it possible to create bitmap cache of shape and use it for `beginBitmapFill`?

now i have code:

```
var shape = new createjs.Shape();

shape.graphics.beginStroke('red').moveTo(0, 0).lineTo(150, 0).lineTo(150, 150).lineTo(0, 150).lineTo(0, 0).moveTo(0, 50).lineTo(150, 50).moveTo(0, 100).lineTo(150, 100).moveTo(50, 0).lineTo(50, 150).moveTo(100, 0).lineTo(100, 150);
shape.cache(0, 0, 150, 150);
//shape.graphics.clear();
//shape.graphics.beginBitmapFill(img); //, "repeat", matrix)
shape.graphics.beginBitmapFill(shape.cacheCanvas);

stage.addChild(shape);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found solution:

```
                var shape = new createjs.Shape();
                shape.graphics.beginStroke('red').moveTo(0, 0).lineTo(150, 0).lineTo(150, 150).lineTo(0, 150).lineTo(0, 0).moveTo(0, 50).lineTo(150, 50).moveTo(0, 100).lineTo(150, 100).moveTo(50, 0).lineTo(50, 150).moveTo(100, 0).lineTo(100, 150);
                shape.cache(0, 0, 150, 150);
                shape.graphics.clear().beginBitmapFill(shape.cacheCanvas).drawRect(0, 0, 300, 300);
                shape.cache(0, 0, 300, 300);
                stage.addChild(shape);
```

Comment: It is a little weird to use the shape's cache as the source for that same shape's bitmap fill. Definitely recommend a secondary shape/cache instead. If it works though, then its probably fine.